# Mercurial ValueError: overflow in dirstate

Tags: version-control, mercurial

When I try to do an **hg status** command, Mercurial raise me **ValueError: overflow in dirstate** error.

**hg log** and **hg diff** commands works fine.

Do you have a way to fix my repo ?

Output of **hg status** command

```
12:12 user@host ~/projects/nsr% hg st
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
** https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) [GCC 4.9.2]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.9.1)
** Extensions loaded: extdiff, color, graphlog, rebase, strip, mq, shelve, churn, purge, record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hg", line 45, in <module>
    mercurial.dispatch.run()
.....
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 888, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: overflow in dirstate
zsh: exit 1     hg st
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally,

I found solution and fix my repository by using this command :

```
hg debugrebuildstate -r tip
```

Comment: didn't work for me, just raised the same `ValueError: overflow in dirstate`

Comment: turns out my syncing software (Pcloud) is terrible and made a conflicted copy of the file `.hg/dirstate` - Reverting to an earlier version of the file `dirstate` fixed it- For general information about repo corruption see [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption)